# Uncrustify function pointer spacing after star

Tags: c, uncrustify

I'm trying to configure uncrustify to beautify the following example:

```
void *( * functionptr1)(int x, void * ptr);
char*(*functionptr2)(int x, void* ptr);
char * ( *functionptr3)(int x, void *ptr);
```

So that it becomes like this:

```
void* (*functionptr1)(int x, void* ptr);
char* (*functionptr2)(int x, void* ptr);
char* (*functionptr3)(int x, void* ptr);
```

So far, using the following configuration:

```
sp_before_ptr_star = remove
sp_after_ptr_star = force
sp_ptr_star_paren = force
sp_inside_tparen = remove
```

I have this

```
void* (* functionptr1)(int x, void* ptr);
char* (* functionptr2)(int x, void* ptr);
char* (* functionptr3)(int x, void* ptr);
```

It's close, but I cannot figure out how to remote the space before function pointer name. Is there a configuration that would allow that?

Comment: why not just write the code the way you want it, rather than expecting some script to fix it for you?

Comment: usefull in git commit hook and whatnot to ensure code uniformity.